# iOS Change the Sent Event of a button from Touch Down to Touch UP Inside?

Tags: ios

Really simple question.   Is there an easy way to change how a button responds within an iOS app?

I've created buttons that are Touch Down, but I think Touch Up Inside would look better.   Is there a quick and easy way to change these within Xcode rather than dragging out buttons again?   I'm more concerned that if I don't do it write I'll make a mess and have to spend ages fixing it!

Comment: Are these actions setup in IB or code?

Comment: I set them up in IB.   Hence why I'm not sure where you can easily change them.   I'd imagine in code it would be fairly easy because you'd have had to specify the action required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the interface builder, you should re-drag (re-connect) the associated action. You can get this dialog by ctrl-clicking the button.

[image: Connecting IBOutlets and IBActions]

You can wire up a button in code (but make sure it is already not connected in IB).

`[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Ok, I'll re-drag if that's the best way!  Thanks.